# Mongoose one-to-many relationship not being populated

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have a one-to-many relationship where a place can have multiple reviews. Here are the 2 schemas

```
export const PlaceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  center: { type: [Number], required: true },
  borders: { type: [], required: true },
  reviews: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Review' }]
});

export const ReviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: { type: String, required: true },
  city: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Place', required: true },
  creation_date: { type: Date, required: true },
  ...
});
```

I have reviews with correct place ID. But when I do a simple `this.placeModel.find().populate('reviews').exec()`, the `reviews` always come back as an empty array. But the IDs seem to be fine, as visible here (place on the left, review on the right)

[image]

It's my first side project where I play with with Mongo, so I don't really see what I'm missing.

Comment: Instead of checking that you have correct place ID in the review documents, you should be checking that you have correct review ID in the place documents if you want the reviews field to be populated with this query `this.placeModel.find().populate('reviews').exec()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query `this.placeModel.find().populate('reviews').exec()` will work in this manner:

1. Find all `place` documents from the `places` collection.
2. For each place document, iterate through the `reviews` field (of array type) and search for the document in the `reviews` collection with the matching id, and replace the array element with the review document.
3. Return the list of place documents where the `reviews` field has been populated with the review documents.

Hence, you need to ensure that your place documents contain the correct id of the review documents in the `reviews` field instead of ensuring that you have the correct place id in the review documents for the query you want to execute.

Comment: Ohhh, ok, it works that way. Ok ok, it works, thanks